# Can't create React project on wsl ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFBft.png)
Guys can you help me, why i can't create react project on wsl ubuntu

I am encountering an issue while trying to create a new React project on WSL Ubuntu. I'm using the command:

```bash
npx create-react-app my-react-app
```

However, I consistently receive the following error:

```bash
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory.
node:fs:1382
  const result = binding.mkdir(
                         ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\react-project'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1382:26)
    at module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\...:23:13)
    at createApp (C:\Users\zzz\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\...:257:6)
    at ...
```

I am running the commands in the WSL terminal, and the path I'm specifying is within my home directory on WSL: \wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\your-username\my-react-app.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Am I missing any configurations or permissions?

Node.js Version: 21.2.0
NPM Version: [Your NPM Version]

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

I am running the commands in the WSL terminal, and the path I'm specifying is within my home directory on WSL: \wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\your-username\my-react-app.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Am I missing any configurations or permissions?

Node.js Version: 21.2.0
NPM Version

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: "operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\react-project'" why are you trying to create your project in the Windows directory!?

Comment: i created the project in default root using wsl terminal